How to make that even if the cube default size is the maxSize or minsize pressing G first time will start scaling?
now the cube default size is 1,1,1 and this is also what i set as the maxSize in the inspector.
when running and pressing the G key nothing happens. only when pressing the G key second time it starts scaling down and then scaling up and working.
but why first time i need to press the G key twice to make it start working?
i want that no matter what the cube default size is and the maxSize and minSize first time pressing the G key it will start scaling.
the automatic part is working fine the scaling with pressing the G key is not working as expected.
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scaling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;

    public bool automatic = false;
    public bool coroutineIsRunning = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (automatic)
        {
            if (!coroutineIsRunning)
            {
                Scale();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
            {
                Scale();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Scale()
    {
        scaleUp = !scaleUp;

        if (scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

        if (scaleUp)
        {
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
        }
        else
        {
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        coroutineIsRunning = true;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            if (counter > duration)
                coroutineIsRunning = false;

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}


add some debug statements and you will follow your code and see

When you first make a cube with a default Vector3(1,1,1), because public bool scaleUp = false; the worflow in Scale() swaps the values: scaleUp = !scaleUp; and thus false -> true.
When the code reaches the decision-making part, it will check:
if (scaleUp)
{
    scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
}
else
{
    scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
}

Now that scaleUp = true, it basically scales to the same size. So from your point of view, it does nothing. When you call it the second time, because it swaps scaleUp again it can now shrink, then pressing G again will make it grow as it normally should.
While you might be tempted to fix it by setting the default value to true, I recommend you setup a logic in Start() where you see if the size is larger or smaller than the maxSize (or default size variable?) so you know whether to make it grow or shrink.
Also, try to simplify your code. The coroutine handling above can easily be rewritten to remove redundant code as:
private void Scale()
{
    scaleUp = !scaleUp;

    if (scaleCoroutine != null)
        StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

    Vector3 targetSize;
    if (scaleUp)
        targetSize = maxSize;
    else
        targetSize = minSize;

    scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, targetSize, duration));
}

... or even simpler, without a separate Vector3 and without an if in just one line:
private void Scale()
{
    scaleUp = !scaleUp;

    if (scaleCoroutine != null)
        StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

    scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, (scaleUp ? maxSize : minSize), duration));
}

